# Visual Studio toolbox items unavailable

Tags: visual-studio, toolbox

I cannot access any items in my Visual Studio Toolbox, they all appear in dark grey indicating I cannot select them. I cannot even set up a button and am unsure what I need to do to get the toolbox items available again.

Screenshot of the toolbox issue, notice how all the options are in dark grey and cannot be selected:
[image: Screenshot of the toolbox issue, notice how all the options are in dark grey and cannot be selected]

Comment: aren't they being shown when you're on the designer view of a form?

Comment: toolbox controls enables when you will be on designer page.

Comment: Probably your project is RUNNING. STOP the project then your toolbar items will become enable.

Answer (score 0):

You must open design page of your winform/WPF.

Answer (score 0):

you should right click on toolbox and 'reset toolbox'.